Spring application runs in IntelliJ IDE but not in webapps folder of tomcat
My code works when I run it normally on IntelliJ IDE with spring provided tomcat server on 8080. But when I change my pom.xml file to create a WAR file and upload it on my local tomcat server which I have changed it to port 8081. It just shows 403 code to the simplest API which does not even have security.
The WAR file gets created successfully and also gets uploaded through tomcat manager app.
I changed my WAR file name to "logindemo".
When I Deploy my WAR file in webapps of Tomcat I run this URL on postman with GET:-
http://localhost:8081/logindemo/auth/welcome
Below is my pom.xml file which I use to create WAR file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.gfg</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot3-security</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot3-security</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot 3 Security</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <jjwt.version>0.11.5</jjwt.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Below is my SecurityConfig.java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthFilter authFilter;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserInfoService(); // Ensure UserInfoService implements UserDetailsService
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()) // Disable CSRF for stateless APIs
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/welcome", "/auth/addNewUser", "/auth/generateToken").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/user/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/admin/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated() // Protect all other endpoints
                )
                .sessionManagement(sess -> sess
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) // No sessions
                )
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider()) // Custom authentication provider
                .addFilterBefore(authFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class); // Add JWT filter

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); // Password encoding
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}

Below is my Controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserInfoService service;

    @Autowired
    private JwtService jwtService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @GetMapping("/welcome")
    public String welcome() {
        return "Welcome this endpoint is not secure";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addNewUser")
    public String addNewUser(@RequestBody UserInfo userInfo) {
        return service.addUser(userInfo);
    }

    @GetMapping("/user/userProfile")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
    public String userProfile() {
        return "Welcome to User Profile";
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin/adminProfile")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public String adminProfile() {
        return "Welcome to Admin Profile";
    }

    @PostMapping("/generateToken")
    public String authenticateAndGetToken(@RequestBody AuthRequest authRequest) {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authRequest.getUsername(), authRequest.getPassword())
        );
        if (authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
            return jwtService.generateToken(authRequest.getUsername());
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid user request!");
        }
    }
}

Below is my LoginApplication.java
@SpringBootApplication
public class LoginApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LoginApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(LoginApplication.class);
    }
}


Share your application.properties and the log output during the start.

And you should permit /error

Also, did you check the tomcat server logs?  A 403 - Forbidden usually means the "server" is not configured to allow that URL and/or port.  401 - Unauthorized would indicate you are not "authorized" for that URL based on your token.

You need to know WHY you are getting 403. Set logging level to debug with logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG so that you see the error. After that paste the error into question

When you deploy with Tomcat Manager, do you specify the contextPath as logindemo?  I setup a minimal runtime (commenting out all the classes you didn't provide)and when I deploy it, it's deploying as a contextPath with http://localhost:8080/springboot3-security-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/auth/welcome, which is what's in your pom.xml...and it works.  Your GET above though shows logindemo GET:-
http://localhost:8081/logindemo/auth/welcome.
